# Create cfthread with arguments and check its running status for cfprogressbar

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion, cfml

Could you please assist me in the question of interactive thread control in ColdFusion. I cannot get the idea of callbacks in ColdFusion, a lack to a newbie coming from asp.net.

I have a page with `cfform` like this:

```
<cfform method="get">
<cfif isDefined("URL.s1")>
<cfselect name="s1" bind="cfc:chart.getS1()" bindonload="true" selected=#URL.s1#/>
<cfelse>
<cfselect name="s1" bind="cfc:chart.getS1()" bindonload="true"/>
</cfif>
<cfif isDefined("URL.s2")>
<cfselect name="s2" bind="cfc:chart.getS2({s1})" selected=#URL.s2#/>
<cfelse>
<cfselect name="s2" bind="cfc:chart.getS2({s1})"/>
</cfif>

<cfif isDefined("URL.m")>
<cfselect name="m">
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="1" to="6" index="Month">
<option value="#Month#" <cfif URL.m EQ Month>selected="selected"</cfif>><cfoutput>#Month# Month<cfif Month GT 1>s</cfif></cfoutput></option>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
<option value="12" <cfif URL.m EQ 12>selected="selected"</cfif>>12 Months</option>
<option value="24" <cfif URL.m EQ 24>selected="selected"</cfif>>24 Months</option>
</cfselect>
<cfelse>
<cfselect name="m">
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="1" to="6" index="Month">
<option value="#Month#" <cfif Month EQ 2>selected="selected"</cfif>>#Month# Month<cfif Month GT 1>s</cfif></option>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
<option value="12">12 Months</option>
<option value="24">24 Months</option>
</cfselect>
</cfif>

<input type="submit" value="Show">
<cfif isUserInRole("admin")>
<input type="submit" name="u" value="Update">
<input type="submit" name="r" value="Re-run">
</cfif>
</cfform>

<!--- Here comes the "event handlers" for the last two buttons --->
<cfif isUserInRole("admin") AND isDefined("URL.s1") AND isDefined("URL.s2") AND isDefined("URL.u")>
<cfsetting requesttimeout="0">
<cfset qSymbols=chart.updatePair(s1, s2)>
</cfif>

<cfif isUserInRole("admin") AND isDefined("URL.s1") AND isDefined("URL.s2") AND isDefined("URL.r")>
<cfsetting requesttimeout="0">
<cfset qSymbols=chart.rerunPair(s1, s2)>
</cfif>

<!--- Then the output results in a table --->
...
```

Some portions of code-behind cfc file:

```
<cffunction name="chartUpdate" output="false" access="remote">
    <cfargument name="s1" required="true" type="string" default="">
    <cfargument name="s2" required="true" type="string" default="">
    <cftry>
    <cfstoredproc procedure="chart_update" returncode="false">
        <cfprocparam value="#s1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="16" type="In">
        <cfprocparam value="#s2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="16" type="In">
        <cfprocresult name="theResponse">
    </cfstoredproc>
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cflog file="News_DBerror" text="Message = #cfcatch.message# Detail= #cfcatch.detail#">
    </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="updatePair" output="false" access="remote">
    <cfargument name="s1" required="true" type="string" default="">
    <cfargument name="s2" required="true" type="string" default="">
    <cfscript>
    ...routine...
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="rerunPair" output="false" access="remote">
    <cfargument name="s1" required="true" type="string" default="">
    <cfargument name="s2" required="true" type="string" default="">
    <cfscript>
    try
    {
        chartUpdate(s1, s2);
    }
    catch (Any ex)
    {
        WriteLog(type="Error", file="News", text="[#ex.type#] #ex.message#");
    }
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

It works as it should. Some of the DB stored procedures take about 20-30 seconds to run, so they fit to the HTTP timeout while the browser keeps indicate waiting for server response and finally page reloads with updated results in a table and database behind. Works for me ok but is not good for modern user experience.

I want to add a `cfprogressbar` by clicking on `Update` or `Re-run` button and  hide all the buttons in the `cfform` (`Show`, `Update` and `Re-run`) while process runs. Finally the page supposed to be auto-reloaded, hide the `cfprogressbar`, show the button controls and new results. (Maybe in `cfdiv/cflayout` ajax way, I'm not experienced in these details.)

What I have done to try `cfprogressbar`.

Added `<cfset session.status = 0>` on top of the page.
Added some javascript functions (some do not work properly and commented out for now, doesn't matter):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initProgressBar()
{
    //document.getElementById('doCFCbar').style.display = 'none';
    ColdFusion.ProgressBar.show('cfcBar');
    ColdFusion.ProgressBar.start('cfcBar');
}
function finProgressBar()
{
    //ColdFusion.ProgressBar.hide('cfcBar');
    //document.getElementById('doCFCbar').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

I replaced the `Rerun` button to test on it:

```
<!---<input type="submit" name="r" value="Rerun">--->
<cfinput type="button" name="doCFCbar" value="Rerun" onclick="initProgressBar()">
<cfprogressbar name="cfcBar" bind="cfc:chart.rerunProgress(URL.s1,URL.s2)" interval="1000" width="200" oncomplete="finProgressBar()">
```

THIS doesn't work as I mentioned later! I can not call any `bind="cfc:function(URL.s1,URL.s2)"` with arguments.

**Here are the questions:** how can implement my idea in ColdFusion? I don't understand the bridge of interactive callbacks between components on `cfm` page and their functions in `cfc` file.

How can I create a thread by clicking on a button, passing arguments and check the thread status?

I added some functions to `cfc` file based on Adam Cameron's [defer()](http://cflib.org/udf/defer) function [from here](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/10/community-collaboration-fixing-some.html) to run as cfthread and check the status.

```
<cffunction name="rerunProgress" output="false" access="remote" returntype="struct">
    <cfargument name="s1" required="true" type="string" default="">
    <cfargument name="s2" required="true" type="string" default="">
<cfscript>
str = StructNew();
str.message = "Processing Data...";

if (NOT IsDefined("session.status"))
{
    session.status = 0.1;

    deferredJob = defer
    (
        job = function()
        {
            chartUpdate(s1, s2);
        },
        onSuccess = function(result)
        {
            // will receive someResult, so do something with it
        },
        onFailure = function(e)
        {
            writeLog(type="Error", file="News", text="[#ex.type#] #ex.message#");
        }
    );
}
else
if (session.status LT 1.0 AND deferredJob.getStatus() == "Running")
{
    session.status += 0.01;
}
else
{
    str.message = "Done.";
    session.status = 1.0;
}
str.status = session.status;
return str;
</cfscript>
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="defer" output="false" access="remote" returntype="struct">
    <cfargument name="job" required="true" type="struct" default="">
    <cfargument name="onSuccess" required="false" type="struct" default="">
    <cfargument name="onFailure" required="false" type="struct" default="">
    <cfargument name="onError" required="false" type="struct" default="">
    <cfargument name="onTerminate" required="false" type="struct" default="">
    <cfscript>
    var deferThread = "";
    try
    {
        cfthread.status = "Running";
        thread name="deferThread" action="run" attributecollection=arguments
        {
            try
            {
                successData.result = job();
                cfthread.status = "Completed";
                if (structKeyExists(attributes, "onSuccess"))
                    onSuccess(successData);
            }
            catch (any e)
            {
                cfthread.status = "Failed";
                if (structKeyExists(attributes, "onFailure"))
                    onFailure(e);
                else
                    rethrow;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (any e)
    {
        cfthread.status = "Errored";
        if (structKeyExists(attributes, "onError"))
            onError(e);
        else
            rethrow;
    }
    return
    {
        getStatus = function()
        {
            return cfthread.status;
        },
        terminate = function()
        {
            if (cfthread.status == "Running")
            {
                thread name="deferThread" action="terminate";
                cfthread.status = "Terminated";
                if (isDefined("onTerminate"))
                    onTerminate();
            }
        }
    };
</cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

NB: Running on ColdFusion2016 / SQL Server 2016

**UPD:** Ok, if no threads (I just tried them out, threads may not be a final or any good solution here, just the way I saw to get current process status (running or finished) with an ability to abort it optionally),

What is the best approach to make a bridge between client page and cfc in such a case? In particular and in general.

(The solution in asp.net is based on built-in callbacks engine so it is completely transparent to pass arguments or 'events' for the developer.)

Am I supposed to do it manually for each type of component in ColdFusion?
Or is there any approach or will be any built-in engine in the next ColdFusion releases, if I catch the situation correctly, didn't I?

Comment: One thing to bear in mind with cfthread is that it completely separate from the what is going on in the user's browser.  That makes things like progress bars difficult.  Another thing is that if you get too carried away with separate threads you could overwhelm your server.  Finally, recognize that asp and cf have many things in common.  They are both used for computer programming and fundamental things like doing one thing at a time apply in both cases.

Comment: ok, I just tried threads out. They may not be a final or any good solution here, just the way I saw to get current process status (running or finished) with an ability to abort it (optionally).